# Is every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ a $G_\delta$ set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The following seems to indicate that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ a $G_\delta$ set:

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $A_n=\bigcup\limits_{a\in A}(a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n})$.

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n$ is an open set.

$A=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, so $A$ is the intersection of a countable no. of open sets

i.e. $A$ is $G_\delta$ set.

I'm pretty sure I've made a mistake, but I can't see where I went wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that intersection is equal to $A$? Try $A=\mathbb Q$ and see what happens.

Comment: BTW, spaces, such that every subset is $G_\delta$ are called Q-set spaces or Q-spaces. If not discrete, they are somehow small, for instance, a separable, metrizable Q-space has cardinality $< 2^\omega$.

Comment: You may be interested in a nice exposition of Polish and Analytic spaces in  chapter $8$ of [Cohn's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6956-8). Measure theory is not a prerequisite until the end of the chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you made a mistake.

For example, let $A=(0, 1)$, then $A_n=(-\frac1n, 1+\frac1n)$.
So $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is...

> $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n=[0, 1]$

For example which is not $G_\delta$-set but subset of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb Q$, this can be seen to be true by Baire category theorem.

Comment: Thank you. I should have been able to figure this out - I'm trying to solve another problem involving $G_\delta$ sets and I think I fried my brain!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers address the flaw in the OP's proof, but there is a quick cardinality argument that has the advantage that it avoids Baire. Since $\mathbb R$ has a countable base for its standard topology, the cardinality of its open sets (which are unions of basis elements) is $2^\omega$. Then, using the definition of the $G_{\delta}$ sets, there can be at most $(2^\omega)^\omega=2^\omega$ of them.So there must be subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are not $G_{\delta}$ sets.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subset A$ is not necessarily true. This is the false step in your reasoning.

For example, Let $A=\{1,\,1/2,\,1/3,\,\dots\}$. Then we see that $$0 \in\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n, \;\;\;A \not\ni 0.$$

For we set $n=j$, fixed; now look at the interval $(\frac{1}{2j}-\frac{1}{j},\,\frac{1}{2j}+\frac{1}{j})$.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $\mathbb{R}$ is a Baire space. That means (definition) that every countable intersection of open dense sets is dense.

Take the set of the irrational numbers and consider $B_{n}=\left\{q_{n} \right\}^{c}$ where $q_{n}$ is the sequence of rational numbers.

It is clear that each $B_{n}$ is open and $A=\bigcap\,B_{n}$ where A the set of irrationals.

Therefore the set of irrationals is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Now we prove that the set of rationals is NOT $G_{\delta}$. Assume it is.

Then it can be written as $\bigcap\,A_{n}$ where $A_{n}$ are open sets.

But since $A_{n}\supset\,\mathbb{Q}$ we get that each $A_{n}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

So we get by the two constructions that $\mathbb{Q}\bigcap\,A=\varnothing$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets which implies that $\varnothing$ is a dense set, clearly a contradiction.

Therefore $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not $G_{\delta}$.